# Taxonomy Page Go to 404 pgae

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am creating one custom post type using the Redux Framework. Creating a category and that category view by category directly and directly go to the link but that link should go to directly 404 page. Please check below code and let me know what was an error in my code.

```
remove_action( 'init', 'brightness_service_register',10 );
add_action( 'init', 'brightness_service_register',1 );   
function brightness_service_register() 
{
$labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Service', 'brightness' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'brightness' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Service', 'brightness'),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Service', 'brightness'),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Service', 'brightness' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Service', 'brightness' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Service', 'brightness' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'No items found', 'brightness' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No items found in Trash', 'brightness' ), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Service'
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'service', 'with_front' => false ),
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' )
   );  

$taxonomy_labels = array(
      'name' => __( 'Service Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'Service Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Category' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Service Categories' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Service Category' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Service Categories' ),
    ); 

$taxonomy_args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $taxonomy_labels,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'service-categories', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
      'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
      'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
   ); 
register_post_type( 'service' , $args );
register_taxonomy('coll-categories', 'service',$taxonomy_args);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings >> Permalink >> Save Changes
```

Done

Comment: No, do not flush rewrite rules on `init`, they should only be flushed once when they change. You also don't have to save changes on the permalinks page, if you look at page source you will see that it flushes rules when you just load the page and do nothing.

Comment: Yes, executing `flush_rewrite_rules()` on `init` is bad, sorry about that :) Instead, it can be added in the plugin/theme activation hook.